# Iframe { height:70%;} not working in IE 8 and Firefox

Tags: html, asp.net, css, iframe

I have a div contained site design in which i have inserted a iframe to load pages.
`header stays at top well`
`footer stays at bottom very well`
`content stays at the middle well too`

But the iframe isn't stretching to the full height of the container. `i have not mentioned height in pixels in the style`

But when i wrote

```
iframe {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  min-height:72%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"> blah blah </div>
  <div id="content">
      <div id="menu"> some code of menu </div>
      <div id="iframeDiv" class="contentdiv">
         <iframe src="#" id="#" width="100%"></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">blah blah</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
 margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%;
}
iframe {
margin:0; padding:0; height:72%; width:100%;
}
#container {
min-height:100%; position:relative; width:100%;
}
#content {
  padding:10px; padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

**I tried writing styles for #iframeDiv but nothing seems to work!**

it stretched till footer, but this works only in chrome. ie is not sensing the background color too. firefox displyed the backgroundcolor but not stretched to 72%. how to stretch iframe height to 72% for all browsers. ? 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time struggle with iframe, I didnt want to enter the height value explicitly(Px). Since giving it in **Px** will vary for browsers i used javascript to calculate the consumed height and subtracted from the window height and assigned it to iframe using jquery. Here is what i did.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var windowheight = $(window).height();
  var headerheight = $("#header").height();
  var footerheight = $("#footer").height();
  var menuheight = $("#patientMenu").height();
  var frameheight = windowheight - (headerheight+footerheight+menuheight+5);
  //alert(contentheight);
  $('#frameset').css ({
   'height' : contentheight
  });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Alright, and if you put this into $(window).resize(function(){...}); then this even works when resizing the browser window.

Comment: Ha ha, you're the man. Forgot that totally! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Check your DOCTYPE of the html page and also you can try to add CSS for the HTML and BODY tag:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: My doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" and i have already added your suggestion Jo. no luck

Comment: So the problem will be, that you have the iframe in a div structure. To get the 100% height working you'll need to have all surrounding div's at 100% height, maybe you'll even need to give them an absolute height in pixels.

Comment: Yeah Jo, I had problem with setting div height since i have mentioned all the parent containers in %. Nothing in px. Finally i used Javascript innerheight, Clientheight properties and set the appropriate window height to the iframe. window.height -(header.height+ footer.height) = iframe height. It worked very well with all the browsers. !